# Styling your action bar android

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

The general action bar in android is quite dull is there any way of editing this bar in terms of colour, style and the position of icons rather than having icons arranged right to left can you have a single icon in the middle this is just an equiry about how far can you customize the action bar or will you just have to nest images in layouts ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html. check this

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is this great online tool which you can use to style your action bar:

http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

This will produce a bunch of styles and images and you can customise it further later.

Comment: Can you remove items of this action bar generator or do you have to use the default ones on the page

Comment: The generator gives you styles and images and you can then edit them as you wish.

Comment: Are there any videos that offers tutorials on this you're awsome man

Comment: Not sure. I managed just by using the generator and checking things on stackoverflow.